# "You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using" on Colima app with Vite

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vite, colima

I'm on Mac M1 and using Colima for a replacement for Docker Desktop. I use Vite as bundler.

I did `docker-compose up` and then got

```
Error:
You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using.
This won't work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to
install a platform-specific binary executable.
```

which didn't make a lot of sense to me as I wasn't copying my `node_modules` folder. If I did, I would have understood why the `@esbuild/darwin-arm6` package is installed on my machine but container needs `@esbuild/linux-x64`. I'm only copying

```
COPY package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./
```

on my `Dockerfile` and running this one line later:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc,dst=/usr/src/app/.npmrc \
    --mount=type=cache,id=npmcache,target=/var/.npm \
    npm ci --only=production --no-optional --prefer-offline --cache /var/.npm
```

so I would expect the container to be created, package files to be copied and `node_modules` to be created with `npm ci`.

When I run `colima ssh`, I see that the files are identical to the host/local file system. I thought when I specify it with

```
volumes:
  - .:/usr/src/app
```

and

```
node_modules/
```

on `.dockerignore`, I'm basically saying that "check the `.dockerignore` file, don't touch the folders there, move to `Dockerfile`, copy `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm ci` and apply the volumes which is basically taking the project directory and 'sync'ing it to the path `/usr/src/app` inside the container",  according to the article [here](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/bigger-dockerignore-smaller-docker-images-49fa22e51c7) which describes the order of execution:

> When we run docker-compose up or any variation of the command, first the docker-compose command is converted into a docker command. Next, the .dockerignore is read and any files in there are ignored. After that, the Dockerfile is read. Of course when we do COPY . . we only copy the files that Docker did not ignore. Then, any volumes are applied, including bind mounts. The volumes do not adhere to the .dockerignore. Finally, if there is a command specified in the docker-compose.yml, that command is run.

But then again, when I do `colima ssh`, I simply am not inside a docker container but still my local file system. (I can navigate and can visit any path outside of the project files). Also, when a modify a file, I can observe the file change locally. Besides, I also see the the supposedly ignored files in `.dockerignore` there (like `dist/`) I must be missing aomething fundamental.

I have started colima with

```
colima start --arch x86_64 --cpu 6 --memory 16 --disk 128 --cpu-type qemu64
```

Comment: That `volumes:` block hides everything in your image and replaces it with content from the host.  If you're trying to do work on source code that lives on your host, you might find it more convenient to just use Node directly and not insert Docker into the workflow.  `volumes:` do not honor `.dockerignore`, that's only used when building the image.  My general recommendation is to remove this `volumes:` block entirely.

Comment: @DavidMaze I just made a similar mistake with `volumes:`, conflating `.dockerignore` entries with any other path excluding behavior. Removing the bind mount as you suggested fixed it. Perhaps your comment could be posted as an answer for more visibility.